# How can I get my Python script to wrap strings with single quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the Python script below that reads data from an Excel spreadsheet and then inserts that data into SQL Server

```
excel_file = 'prod_data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

systemDesign_columns = ['dateCreated', 'systemSecure', 'isUsingFirewall','systemStartYear', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'systemDescription'] 

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    systemDesign_values = [str(row[column]) for column in systemDesign_columns]
    systemDesign_values_str = ', '.join(systemDesign_values)

    commands = f"""
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.systemDesign (dateCreated, systemSecure, isUsingFirewall, systemStartYear, firstName, lastName, systemDescription) VALUES ({systemDesign_values_str});
    
    """
    insert_statements.append(commands)
    
for statement in insert_statements:
print(statement)
```

This script does run without errors, but how can I enclose the string values in single quotes?

Here is an example of what it generates:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.systemDesign (dateCreated, systemSecure, isUsingFirewall,systemStartYear, firstName, lastName, systemDescription) VALUES (2023-06-01 00:00:00, 1, 0, 2022, Jim, Williams, A user network);
```

You can see that there are some string fields.

Is there a way to only enclose the string fields in single quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not use string formatting to generate a SQL command. Use your SQL library's implementation of parameterized queries.

Comment: You could wrap the `systemDesign_columns` strings in double quotes e.g. `"'dateCreated'"`, but @chepner is right here...

Comment: @JRiggles thanks! Where would I do the double quotes wraping?

Comment: @chepner thanks!  Do you have an example of that?  I'm not sure I understand ... thanks again

Comment: In the `systemDesign_columns` list: `systemDesign_columns = ["'dateCreated'", "'systemSecure'" ...`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but since you're using an f string couldn't you just put the single quotes in the places you want them?

```
VALUES ('{systemDesign_values_str}')

commands = f"""

    INSERT INTO dbo.systemDesign (dateCreated, systemSecure, isUsingFirewall, systemStartYear, firstName, lastName, systemDescription) VALUES ('{systemDesign_values_str}');

    """
```

Comment: For the SQL Insert, I need to have the string values wrapped in single quotes.  But not the integer values...I can't figure out how to wrap only some values

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to wrap every single value from the `systemDesign_values` list you can try replacing `systemDesign_values_str = ', '.join(systemDesign_values)` with
`systemDesign_values_str = ', '.join([f"'{value}'" for value in systemDesign_values])`